# How to check if connection pools are cleared

Tags: c#, firebird

I want to rename database file and even I use `using` with connection every time I have to call:

```
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

The problem is that this method doesn't block the thread and I don't know how to check if all connections are cleared, because if I get value from:

```
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.ConnectionPoolsCount
```

It is zero immediately after the method, but I am still not able to rename the database file. If I set some timeout after the method (I tried 1s) then the file is not locked and I can rename it. The problem is that this timeout could be certainly different on different machines.

FWIK the only other method how to check if the file is not locked is to try the renaming in the loop with some timeout, but I can not be sure if the lock is made by connections from my application or from somewhere else.
So is there a better way, how I can wait until this method clears the connections?

Comment: May be this will help :http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq10/

Comment: @ValMarinov I know that on my testing scenario I have connection only from my application so it is my application which locks the file, but I don't know for how long...

Comment: Forcing a shutdown of the database file might be a better approach, this will forcibly close existing connections. See [Database Startup and Shutdown](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gfix-dbstartstop.html)

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel I agree that your approach is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making it an answer for the sake of formatting lists.

@Artholl you can not safely rely upon your own disconnection for a bunch of reasons.

1. There may be other programs connected, not only this your running program. And unless you connect with SYSDBA or database creator or RDB$ADMIN role - you can not query if there are other connections now. *However, you can query, from `MON$ATTACHMENTS`, the connections made with the same user as your `CURRENT_CONNECTION`. This might help you to check the state of your application's own pool. Just that there is little practical value in it.*
2. in Firebird 3 in SuperServer mode there is the LINGER parameter, it means that server would keep the database open for some time after the last client disconnects, expecting that if some new client might decide to connect again then the `PAGE CACHE` for DB file is already in place. Like for middle-loaded WWW servers.
3. even in Firebird 2 every open database has some caches, and it would be installation-specific (firebird.conf) and database specific (gfix/gstat) how large the caches are. After the engine seeing all clients disconnected decided the database is to be closed - it starts with flushing the caches and demanding OS to flush their caches too ( there is no general hardware-independent way to demand RAID controllers and disks themselves to flush caches, or Firebird would try to make it too ). By default Firebird caches are small and preempting them to hardware layer should be fast, but still it is not instant.
4. Even if you checked that all other clients did disconnected, **and then** you disconnected yourself, **and then** you correctly guessed how long to wait for Linger and Caches, even then you still are not safe. You are subject to **race conditions**. At the very time you start doing something requiring explicit owning of DB there may happen some new client that would concurrently open his new connection.

So the correct approach would be not merely proving there is no database connection right NOW, but also ensuring there CAN NOT be any new connection in future, until you re-enable it.

So, as Mark said above, you have to use Shutdown methods to bring the database into no-connections-allowed state. And after you've done with file renaming and other manipulations - to switch it back to normal mode.

https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gfix-dbstartstop.html

Answer (score 3):

If I was responsible for maintaining the firebird provider, I wouldn't want users to rely on such functionality.

Other applications could have the file open (you're only in control of connection pools in the current `AppDomain`), and the server might be running some kind of maintenance on the database.

So even if you *can* wait for the pools to be cleared, I'd argue that if you really really have to mess with these files, a more robust solution is to stop the firebird service instead (and wait for it to have fully stopped).

Comment: I know that I have control only over "my" connections, but it is still good to know how I could check if I actually have active connection, or not. Your idea is better. It is not ideal either, because someone can connect to the file from other computer, but it is definitely more robust, as you wrote.

Comment: @Artholl Database files shouldn't be shared; they should only be accessed through the Firebird server.

Comment: Note that it isn't necessary to shutdown the entire Firebird server, you can shutdown an individual database (see my comment on the question).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I didn't know that was possible, that comes a lot closer to the intent of the question.

Comment: Well, the need to maintain database was not born yesterday, so the measures are already there for years :-) They are not always fashionable and slick-looking, but they usually are present one way or another.